# MySQL: Counting number of staff

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I'm very new to programming in sql and I'm having an issue with a question.

I have to find the department with the largest number of staff, and I'm not at all sure how to do it.

The tables i can use are

[image: here]

I think the end result would have the columns, Department_no and Max(Count(Department_no)) but I'm not sure how I'd get this? Or is there a simpler way that I'm just not seeing?

**EDIT** So far I have

`SELECT Department_no, Count(Department_no)
 FROM ManagerOrBoss
 GROUP BY Department_no;`

But I ideally want to find the maximum of the count, but SQL keeps giving a 'Invalid use of group function error'.

Comment: Is there any department table??

Comment: No, I had to make the table into third normal form (which hopefully I did correctly) and deemed it a non-essential table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You can use count with group by clause in your query as shown below

```
 select Department_no, count(Staff_id) from ManagerOrBoss
 group by department_no
 order by count(staff_id) limit 1
```

Comment: what if there are 2 departments with same no of staff ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid The user wanted to know how to get the department having maximum no. of staffs. Anyways thanks for pointing out on the department having same max count of staffs. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get the department(s) who have higher no. of staff

```
select a.Department_no ,count(a.Staff_id) maxstaffa
from table a
cross join (
    select count(Staff_id) maxstaffb
    from table
    group by Department_no 
    order by maxstaffb desc
    limit 1
) b
group by a.Department_no
having maxstaffa = b.maxstaffb
```

> Note above query can return more than one departments if they all have same max count of staff members

Answer (score 0):

Some more database-inclined folks may be able to tell us why this is a very bad idea, but to get the deparment(s) with the highest number of members I would do something like:

```
SELECT Department_no, COUNT(Staff_id) TheCount
FROM ManagerOrBoss
GROUP BY Department_no
HAVING TheCount = (
    SELECT MAX(Num) 
    FROM (
        SELECT Department_no, COUNT(Staff_id) Num 
        FROM ManagerOrBoss 
        GROUP BY Department_no
    ) as A
)
```

Apologies if my syntax is a bit off. I usually work in MSSQL, but tried to adapt this to MySQL.